# two async tasks works together. One blocks another one

Tags: python, async-await, python-asyncio

I have two async tasks.

`update_x` updates `x` every 1 seconds, and `take_action` will detect the change for `x` and print `x`.

If I remove `await asyncio.sleep(1)` in take_action. the value of `x` will never been printed. The program stucks in while loop in `take_action`. Can someone explain why `asyncio.sleep(1)` is important here?

Below is the simplified code. In reality, `update_x()` is used to subscribe an url, it will publish data. And take_action is used to detect some value change in the data. Is there a better way to design this?

```
 import asyncio
 x = 0
 
 
 def print_x():
     print("x is {}".format(x))
 
 
 async def take_action():
     y = x
     while True:
         if y != x:
             y = x
             print_x()
         **await asyncio.sleep(1)**
 
 
 async def update_x():
     global x
     while True:
         x += 1
         await asyncio.sleep(2)
 
 
 async def main(loop):
     print('creating task')
     task1 = loop.create_task(update_x())
     task2 = loop.create_task(take_action())
     await task1
     await task2
 
 
 if __name__ == '__main__':
     loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()
     loop.run_until_complete(main(loop))
     loop.close()
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Can someone explain why `asyncio.sleep(1)` is important here?

Because without it you are left with a loop that doesn't `await` anything, and therefore never yields control to the event loop (and thereby to other coroutines). `sleep` helps because it suspends the current coroutine, giving the event loop a chance to execute other runnable tasks.

In other words, async/await is based on cooperative multitasking, and a non-awaiting loop doesn't cooperate.

> Is there a better way to design this?

The way to write that code without introducing arbitrary sleeps is by using a synchronization device. [`asyncio.Event`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/asyncio-sync.html#asyncio.Event) is simple and a good match for this use case:

```
async def take_action(evt):
    y = x
    while True:
        if y != x:
            y = x
            print_x()
        await evt.wait()  # wait for x to change
        evt.clear()

async def update_x(evt):
    global x
    while True:
        x += 1
        evt.set()         # notify take_action that we've changed x
        await asyncio.sleep(2)

async def main(loop):
    evt = asyncio.Event()
    task1 = loop.create_task(update_x(evt))
    task2 = loop.create_task(take_action(evt))
    await task1
    await task2
```

Another popular approach is to use a [queue](https://docs.python.org/3/library/asyncio-queue.html) to transfer objects between two (or more) coroutines.